# How to implement currency switcher in django project

Tags: django, django-templates, currency

To make an attempt to create currencies switcher i've added [django-money app](https://django-money.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'djmoney',
    'djmoney.contrib.exchange',
]
```

There is `Product` model with `price` field in `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from djmoney.models.fields import MoneyField

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    price = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2,   
    default_currency='USD')
```

Here `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', HomePageView.as_view()),
]
```

Here `views.py`:

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView ,TemplateResponseMixin):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        product = Product.objects.first()
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["product"] = product 
        return context
```

and template `home.html`:

```
<body>
    <h1> Price {{product.price}}</h1>
</body>
```

There is `Product` instances price rendered in the `home.html` template. I would like to add ability to switch between different currencies and render a corresponding price(if price value `$1` after switching to euro currency it should become `~0,88€`). I supposed that there are should be some built in `template tags` in `django-money app` to convert price in the `home.html` template, but i didn't find any, maybe i missed smthing. Could you please share some experience from your projects and give some tips which way to implement this idea is the easiest and the best, from where to start, cause I'm stuck..

Comment: Do you want to recalculate it (so when you save 1USD you would like to display ~1,1EUR) or do you simply want to change unit?

Comment: As is, your question is way too broad (cf https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), and indications like "I tried" and "I failed" are rather useless.  Please edit your post to describe _exactly_ what you've done and what _exact_ issues you got. FWIW, we've implemented something similar (using another django app) and it's not exactly rocket science either.

Comment: @bruno, thanks for your comment and attention. Question edited, hope it became a little bit clearer now.

Comment: Yes that's _much_ better indeed (close vote retracted).

Comment: Did you try this https://django-money.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#format-localization ?

Comment: @bruno, yes, i tried.. If i get it right, tag {% money_localize money_object %} helps to represent MoneyField() instance in traditional local format (like $1 for dollars and 1€ for euro). What i need is rather this: [https://django-money.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#working-with-exchange-rates] , but it works in python code (`convert_money(Money(100, 'EUR'), 'USD')`) not in the template. Maybe you can suggest some solution..

Comment: @gonczor, `(so when you save 1USD you would like to display ~1,1EUR)` - yes, exactly this way!